# Multiple view controllers subscribe to bluetooth notification

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, bluetooth

guys, 
   I am new to the iOS development. I designed a class A that implements CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate. 
   Also. there is a protocol that kinda wrapped the bluetooth notifications in an easy to understand methods.

My questions now, i have multiple view controllers that needs to respond to the bluetooth notifications. I am not sure how to make it work. Do I make my view controllers delegates of my class A? It seems kinda awkward. Whats the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your design correctly, you are wrapping whatever notifications you need to handle and whatever delegate callbacks that are being sent back to you with the class A - I think it's not awkward at all, just define a protocol for this class to establish good delegation to whatever other classes in your project need these services and hook them up. It would also be best in my opinion to set this class up as a singleton so that it will be the only one managing the callbacks and notifications and it will be easily accessible throughout the application.

Good luck